# SelectedItem of dropdown menu c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have done this a million times and have no clue what I am missing here.... The only difference is I am not hard coding in the drop down menu values, I am dynamically adding them via a query. I will post what I have below...

**ASP.NET:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="drpDownMenu" runat="server" CssClass="fields" EnableViewState="true">
      <asp:ListItem Text="<Select Device>" Value="0" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

**C#:**

```
private void PopulateDeviceDropDown()
    {
        DataTable dtDrpDownListItems = new DataTable();
        string selecItems = "myQuery this works and loads fine";

        try
        {
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(selecItems , sqlConn);
            sqlConn.Open();
            adapter.Fill(dtDrpDownListItems);
            drpDownMenu.DataSource = dtDrpDownListItems;
            drpDownMenu.DataTextField = "Number";
            drpDownMenu.DataBind();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //do something here
        }

        finally
        {
            sqlConn.Close();
        }          
        drpDownMenu.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("<Select Device>", "0"));
    }


 protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string test = "";
        test = drpDownMenu.SelectedItem.Text;
    }
```

In the above the the `PopulateDeviceDropDown` works great.. does what it is suppose to do.

The following `btnSave_Click` also is getting fired, but the `test` variable always returns `<Select Device>` no matter what selection I make...

Am I missing something obvious here? It should return the item I selected, but is returning first item in menu regardless..

Any advice?

Comment: in button click you are getting value from drpDownLoadNewDevice how ever you are adding items to drpDownMenu, you sure that how it supposed to be?

Comment: you are also missing setting DataValuefield(). Set drpDownMenu.DataValueField

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include in you page load

```
(!IsPostback)
{
   PopulateDeviceDropDown()

}
```

Comment: Yeah, I have got that I just didn't post it in here

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but I would try removing

```
<asp:ListItem Text="<Select Device>" Value="0" />
```

and replacing it with code:

```
drpDownMenu.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("<Select Device>", "0"));
drpDownMenu.Items.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

HTH

Comment: i dont think so this is his problem, i dont see drpDownLoadNewDevice population any where in his code nor i see drpDownLoadNewDevice in asp page